# Spectral Representation of the Green's Function

Tags: proof-verification, greens-function

I have been given an exam question asking to show that the spectral representation of the Green's Function for a given Hermitian Operator admits solutions of a given form. I have an answer, but the catch is my university doesn't give ANY solutions to past exams, so I'm not sure whether to back my method or not. There is a another method in my notes, but I just wondered whether or not this solution is legitimate.

[The Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zKl6.jpg)

My solution goes as follows...

$$G(x,t)=\sum_n \frac1\lambda_n \phi_n(x)\phi_n(t)$$

Consider the differential equation:

$$L(x)y(x)=f(x)$$

$L(x)$ admits a complete set of orthogonal eigenfunctions, so we may write:

$$y(x)=\sum_na_n\phi_n(x),f(x)=\sum_nb_n\phi_n(x)$$

Applying $L(x)$ to $y(x)$ yields:

$$L(x)y(x)=\sum_na_nL(x)\phi(x)=\sum_na_n\lambda_n\phi_n(x)=f(x)=\sum_nb_n\phi_n(x)$$

Leading to:

$$a_n\lambda_n=b_n$$

Multiplying $G(x,t)$ by $f(t)$ gives:

$$G(x,t)f(t)=\sum_n\frac1\lambda_n\phi_n(x)\phi_n(t)b_n\phi_n(t)$$

Using the relation between $a_n$ and $b_n$:

$$=\sum_na_n\phi_n(x)\phi_n(t)\phi_n(t)$$

Integrating:

$$\int G(x,t)f(t)dt=\int \sum_na_n\phi_n(x)\phi_n(t)\phi_n(t)dt$$
$$=\sum_na_n\phi_n\int \phi_n(t)\phi_n(t)dt$$

Noticing that this integral is just the inner product of a real function with itself, we conclude that, if the eigenfunctions are normalized, the inner product is just 1. This leads to the required result:

$$\int G(x,t)f(t)dt=\sum_na_n\phi_n(x)=y(x)$$

I'm not sure whether or not there is any spurious reasoning anywhere, so I'd appreciate a more experienced/confident mathematician's approval!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you referring to the convergence of the sum? I must admit when I started the problem my initial response was "On what interval are we talking about here?" - usually the set up to the question is fairly explicit. The exam is a Maths Methods for Theoretical Physics module, so generally the department aren't sticklers for details like convergence in an exam, but in the real world I see how it would be a problem. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: When you first multiply $G$ with $f$, I think you need two dummy indices.